# Non-vanishing of a higher direct image

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, birational-geometry

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a small birational morphism between threefolds. Assume $X$ has terminal singularities and the relative Picard of $f$ is $1$. Suppose the exceptional locus of $f$ is a curve $C$, and let $L$ be a Cartier divisor on $X$. Suppose I know $H^1(C, \mathcal{O}_C(L)) \neq 0$, then can I conclude that $R^1f_*\mathcal{O}_X(L)$ is also non-zero?

Comment: Is $X$ smooth or at least mildly singular (rational singularities)?

Comment: Also, what do you know about $C$?

Comment: @KarlSchwede Yes $X$ has terminal singularities and the relative Picard of $f$ is $1$. I don't think there is anything particular about $C$. In fact, this problem comes from a short argument of Kawamata's paper "crepant blowing up of 3-dim canonical singularities and its application to degeneration of surfaces".(See proof of Lemma 4.2) .

Comment: Can't you just look at $0\to I_C(L)\to O_X(L)\to O_C(L)\to 0$ and then $R^2f_*(I_C(L))=0$ by dimension reasons and so $R^1f_*O_X(L)\to R^1f_*O_C(L)$ is onto. But since $R^1f_*O_C(L)=H^1(O_C(L))\ne 0$ it follows that $R^1f_*O_X(L)\ne 0$?

Comment: Yes! I see what do you mean, thank you very much!!